# how to check if bodymovin animation is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bodymovin

I want the to destroy the animation when is complete animating. tried `addEventListener` that didn't work.

```
anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(params);
animContainer.addEventListener("complete", myScript);

function myScript(){
      anim.destroy();
}
```

Comment: It might be that you defined the function *after* the `addEvenListener`, try putting the function at the top first.

Comment: WOW! lol! just noticed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go would be to listen for native 'transitionend' event on the element that is being animated.

```
element.addEventListener("transitionend", anim.destroy());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(animData);
  anim.addEventListener("complete", function() {
    anim.destroy();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following coded work...

```
  anim.addEventListener("complete", function(){
      anim.destroy());
  });
```